# Json Writer generates extra characters at the end of JSON file C#

Tags: c#

When serializing a json file after updating one of the fields, in this case `Stock`. 
For every character that is lost in the JSON file, the writer generates an extra character at the end of the JSON file.

---

There is **no problem** when increasing the number of characters in the file. For example:-

> When going up from 9 to 10 there is an extra digit(character) that's
>   added to the JSON file. Bringing the total number of characters in the
>   file from 1 to 2.

However, **the problem** arises when reducing the number of digits. For example:-

> When going down from 10 to 9 you lose a digit, bringing the total
>   number of characters from 2 to 1.

For this my code writer compensates for the loss of the total characters by adding in an extra character. In my case it adds and extra ']' at the end of the JSON file.

Removing more characters than 1 leads to them being compensated in the form of whatever is at the end of the file. Writing in reverse from end.

---

*Asp.net core webapp*

**Json File** Initial

```
[
    {
            "Id": "123456",
            "Name": "Ball",
            "Stock": 10
     },
    {
            "Id": "234567",
            "Name": "Apple",
            "Stock": 10
    }
]
```

**Json File** After the ReduceStock method is called

```
[
    {
            "Id": "123456",
            "Name": "Ball",
            "Stock": 9
     },
    {
            "Id": "234567",
            "Name": "Apple",
            "Stock": 10
    }
]]
```

---

**Product model**

```
public class Product
{    
     public string ProductID { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public int Stock { get; set; }

     public override string ToString() => JsonSerializer.Serialize<Product>(this);
}
```

**Service**

```
public JsonFileShoesService(IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment)
{
     WebHostEnvironment = webHostEnvironment;
}

public IWebHostEnvironment WebHostEnvironment { get; }

private string ProductFileName
{
     get { return Path.Combine(WebHostEnvironment.WebRootPath, "data", "path.json"); }
}

public IEnumerable<Product> GetProducts()
{
      using (var jsonFileReader = File.OpenText(ProductFileName))
      {
          return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ShoesOnly[]>(jsonFileReader.ReadToEnd(), new JsonSerializerOptions
           {
                    PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
           });
      }
}
```

**Method in service**

```
public void ReduceStock(string productID)
{
       IEnumerable<Product> product = GetProducts();
       Product selectedProduct = product.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == productID);
       selectedProduct.Stock--;

       using (var outputStream = File.OpenWrite(ProductFileName))
       {
           JsonSerializer.Serialize<IEnumerable<Product>>(
               new Utf8JsonWriter(outputStream, new JsonWriterOptions
               {
                   SkipValidation = true,
                   Indented = true,
               }),
           product
           );
       }
}
```

---

The method is for whenever a product is bought the product stock gets reduced.

Open to suggestions if you have a better way to handle this.

Comment: have you tried with even less characters? It looks like your code simply overwrites whatever is in the file but leaves the extra characters there.

Comment: @LaurentS. removing more characters leads to them being compensated in the form of whatever is at the end of the file. Writing in reverse from end.

Comment: This behavior is described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.openwrite?view=netframework-4.8). You would need to find another way of doing it. My suggestion would be to delete the file and create a new one...

Comment: This has nothing to do with JSON. The code writes to the file the wrong way. It writes over existing text instead of replacing the file

Answer (score 2):

Use [File.CreateText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.createtext?view=netframework-4.8) instead of [File.OpenWrite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.openwrite?view=netframework-4.8).

As the [OpenWrite remarks section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.openwrite?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) explains :

> For an existing file, it does not append the new text to the existing text. Instead, it overwrites the existing characters with the new characters.
>
> If you overwrite a longer string (such as "This is a test of the OpenWrite method") with a shorter string (such as "Second run"), the file will contain a mix of the strings ("Second runtest of the OpenWrite method").

On the other hand, `CreateText`'s description says:

> Creates or opens a file for writing UTF-8 encoded text. If the file already exists, its contents are overwritten.

Answer (score 2):

It is not writing extra characters, it's just leaving the existing ones in place.

This is the expected behavior as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.openwrite?view=netframework-4.8)

> For an existing file, it does not append the new text to the existing text. Instead, it overwrites the existing characters with the new characters. If you overwrite a longer string (such as "This is a test of the OpenWrite method") with a shorter string (such as "Second run"), the file will contain a mix of the strings ("Second runtest of the OpenWrite method").

Using a streamwriter you could specify whether you want to overwrite the existing file, hence doing exactly what you expected to do.
You could aswell delete the file and create a new one depending on your business needs. This last option is not the most elegant one and might also be forbidden (as specified in the comments, a given process might well be authorized to overwrite a file while not being allowed to create/delete a filed inthe very same folder)

Comment: `File.CreateText` will overwrite any existing file

Comment: I agree. It's also closer to the current code of the OP. That said my answer is also a valid one, no?

Comment: I didn't say it isn't. Instead of explicitly deleting the file it's common to overwrite it though. This maps to setting the `CREATE_ALWAYS` flag in the [CreateFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea) Win32 API call. A process may *not* have permissions to delete/create files in a folder, even though it can still overwrite the file

Comment: Yes you're right, deleting the file is not the best solution as it may not be possible at all. I will update my answer slightly.